# Wake QThread from Windows event

Tags: c++, windows, qt, qthread, qtcore

I wanted to have a sleeping thread that will be waked when a specifc USB device is inserted (VID and PID matches the ones I am expecting). How may I connect QThreads to Windows native notifications and make this work?

Comment: I know how to wake up a thread in Qt using wakeOne() and wakeAll(), I just don't have a clue about how to make Windows it self wake a specific Thread when a USB device arrives

Comment: Which Qt version are you using?

Comment: 5.1.1 (10 more characters left)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [QAbstractNativeEventFilter](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qabstractnativeeventfilter.html) to make a subclass for your Windows event.

As for your thread, you could use [QWakeCondition](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qwaitcondition.html) to wait for this event to happen.

Comment: Ok, I will take a look on that

Comment: not yet, I have some code that has to be done ASAP so I can only take a look at this later :/

Comment: @mFeinstein: any progress?

Comment: I actually had to remove this feature from my project due to time constrains and I wont be developing it any more (it was my final year project and now I graduated so...)....what's better: Choose this as the answer even though I didnt test it, leave it as it is, or deleting the question entirely?

Comment: @mFeinstein: since it is a useful question with an imho valid answer, do not delete it. As for selecting an answer, I will leave it with your discretion, but if you do not deal with it anymore, it will never get an approved answer then...

Comment: ...then maybe someone else will find this when he has this problem and he will test it and tell us if that worked for him or not and I can close it I guess...

Comment: @mFeinstein: no, selected answers are not for what works for others, but it is what works for the OP...

Comment: FOR THE RECORD: I cant test this but this sounds like a good answer and something that will work, maybe windows wont send an event with the PID and VID but I guess its ok to presume that windows can send an event like "I have a new USB device" and your program can see if it matches your PID/VID pair or not...so I am marking this as an anser but if this fails to someone, please let me know!